# Apache Lucene Query Iterate through all queries / terms

Tags: java, lucene

I have an interface that enforces implementing classes to define and implement a function that returns an `org.apache.lucene.search.Query`. These classes create various queries like `TermQuery`, `PhraseQuery`, etc. Is it possible to take the `org.apache.lucene.search.Query` that gets returned and iterate over all of the queries and terms it's comprised of?

```java
public interface BaseQuery {

    public Query getQuery();

    default Query toQuery() {
        Query query = getQuery();
        // iterate through Query and do things to each term
        return query;
    }
}
```

```java
public class ContainsQuery implements BaseQuery {
    
    @Override
    protected Query getQuery() {
        PhraseQuery.Builder queryBuilder = new PhraseQuery.Builder();
        queryBuilder.add(new Term("field", "value");
        return queryBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can't [update the changes](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Query.html) (`setTerms` or similar), not even [in this implementation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/PhraseQuery.html) (`PhraseQuery`), maybe this works.

You could first retrieve them, and loop over them. Whatever modification you wish to do, update the term or create a new one, or even discard those unwanted.

Then, assign `query` to a newly constructed object with the modified terms. Something like a manual *update/set* for a **`Query`** object. In the example I just add the terms to the `builder`, but you could include the previous parameters as well (`slop`, ...).

---

```
default Query toQuery() 
{
    Query query = getQuery();
    Term[] terms= query.getTerms();
    List<Term> modifiedTerms = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Term t : terms)
    {
        /*Your modifications here f.e --> you copy one, create two terms and discard one
         Term toAdd=null;
         toAdd= t.clone();
         ...
         toAdd = new Term((t.field()+"suffix"), t.text());
         ...
         toAdd = new Term("5","6"); 
         ...
         (do nothing-discard)

         if (toAdd!=null)
            modifiedTerms.add(toAdd);*/
    }
    
    PhraseQuery.Builder builder = new PhraseQuery.Builder();
    for (int i=0;i<modifiedTerms.size();i++)
         builder.add(modifiedTerms.get(i),i);
    
    query = builder.build();  
    return query;                               
} 
       /* override the reference and assign a new one very similar to s 
         set/update, if those where implemented.                               
          The last query will be erased on the next GC 
          so there's not a big gap here. Also this is most surely 
          a not needed micro-optimization, no worries. */
```

Comment: `.getTerms()` is the key to what I want to do but unless I am missing something it doesn't exist on `org.apache.lucene.search.Query`:
https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_1_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Query.html?is-external=true

Maybe there's a better base class to return?

Comment: I now realize my question wasn't clear on the exact part that was giving me trouble. Your answer definitely solves one half of the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is using the `QueryTermExtractor`.

```java
WeightedTerm[] terms = QueryTermExtractor.getTerms(query);

for (WeightedTerm term : terms) {
    System.out.println("THE TERM: " + term.getTerm());
}
```

The issue I was having is that all examples I found were calling `.getTerms()` on a `org.apache.lucene.search.Query` but `.getTerms()` seems to no longer be implemented on the base `Query` class.

Also, @aran's suggested approach of constructing a new `Query` object is an appropriate method to "modifying" the terms on an already constructed immutable `Query` object.